# CSS Bar-type Menu

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to solve the logic of user interfaces for a while. Completely new as you can imagine, and still digging into CSS stuff.

I'm trying to create a "bar type" menu where the inner part has a fixed width, with logo on the left and menu items on the right. Here is a picture to tell you what I mean:

[image: Upper Bar - Centered Menu]

Here is how far I've gone:
http://cssdeck.com/labs/31sxhkiv

The problem is: I have no idea about how I should put the menu items up there to the right of the loating center-part of the bar.. I've tried floating them to the right (the order changes) and giving them an absolute value... none of them helped.

I'm sure I'm missing a point, so wanted to give SO a shot about this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#content{
    background-color: gray;
    height: 25px;
    width: 600px;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    position:relative;    /* ADD THIS LINE */
}
#menu{                    /* ADD THIS STYLES */
    position:absolute;
    right:0px;
    top:0px;
}
```

Comment: This one did the trick! Thank you! Btw, am I doing this interface the correct way?
Also, I completely understand the absolute positioning there, but what's going on about the relative ?!

Comment: @Zettam if you remove the `relative` position for the parent, than the `absolute` positioned child will *go out of home* :) Remove `relative` from the parent and try your self to see the 'issue'!

Comment: So, when we need to absolute-position stuff, we need to check their parents first if I understand you correct..

Answer (score 1):

I really don't think absolute positioning is what you want, because it's a pain to add new items later. [Here's my fork of your cssdeck](http://cssdeck.com/labs/actg2xh0). I think this is closer to what you wanted, but you'll have to make that call.  My main idea is to make your menu items `inline-block` with `position:relative` so that items will render in the right order and layout nicely. Even with relative positioning, you can nudge items left or right using `margin`.

### Edit

I created a new fork which I think saved my work this time. Also, I decided to go ahead and leave in the `float` paradigm, because that's probably more what you wanted. The trick is to set up `#menu` to float right, while the menu items float left. I didn't think to add it, but you'll probably want to add a new line to clear the floating behavior:

```
#menu:after { clear:float; }
```

Comment: Hey thank you for the reply, but I see everything almost the same with my previous cssdeck

Comment: Looks like I forgot to save. I'll try again and edit the link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `ul` with `li` items `display: inline` and position it absolutely inside a relatively positioned container.